# Java Class Initialization Order

Tags: java, member

I've been programming in Java for over 2 years now, and I just decided to pay close attention to a detail for member variables, and it struck curiosity into me about how a class is initialized.

I'm working on a game, and in my class, `GameStateMenu`, which extends `GameState`, I have this member variable:

```
private int buttonPadding = 10;
```

I have an `init()` method that is inherited by force from the `superclass` (called from the `superclass constructor`), and if I call `System.out.println(buttonPadding)` inside of that `init()` method, it prints out `0`.

There's also an `update()` method inside of the `GameStateMenu` class, and I put the same line of code, `System.out.println(buttonPadding)`, inside of it, and it keeps printing out `10.`

`GameState` class:

```
public abstract class GameState {

    public GameState() {
        init();
    }

    protected abstract void init();

    public abstract void load();

    public abstract void update();

    public abstract void render();

    public void dispose() {
        return;
    }
}
```

`GameStateMenu` class:

```
public class GameStateMenu extends GameState {

    ...
    private int buttonPadding = 10;

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        System.out.println(buttonPadding); // prints out 0
        ...
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void update() {
        System.out.println(buttonPadding); // prints out 10
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

What I don't understand is why `buttonPadding` is `0` when the `init()` method is called, but once the class is fully initialized, and the `update()` method is being called, regularly, `buttonPadding` has been initialized and is printing out `10`. Why does it does this and/or what is the initialization order for Java?

Although, if I made `buttonPadding` static, it works correctly, but I'm still curious about why the member variable isn't set.

Comment: You may want to consider creating a [minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the situation to demonstrate the situation more clearly.

Comment: Can you post the actual code in question? I'm a little confused with your description. If buttonPadding is a global variable, I think it needs to be declared `static`, otherwise it's actually a member variable and GameState would not have access to it.

Comment: I updated the post with some code, and fixed my grammer about calling it a `global variable` instead of a `member variable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent class (`GameState`) gets fully initialized before the child class (`GameStateMenu`). That means that the `GameState` constructor gets called before any initialization takes place in `GameStateMenu`, so at that point `buttonPadding` still has the default value for an unassigned int, which is zero. After `GameState` gets fully initialized, `GameStateMenu` gets initialized - first `buttonPadding` gets set to zero, then the constructor gets called.

Unsolicited Advice:
It's usually a Bad Idea for a parent class constructor to call methods defined in child classes. It allows child classes to break invariants in the parent. In this particular case, it looks like you might want an interface instead of an abstract class, but it's hard to say without knowing more about your code.